# Export IE report to excel using VBA where export drop down menu exists

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, export-to-excel

I am using vba to pull a date specific report fr m our report server. I was able to bypass the date picker by entering the date parameters into the URL. The next step is to export the report to excel. it has a drop down to select the file type. How do I get the code to select the from the drop down? I have tried many variations of the code below.

```
    Sub Report()
    Dim ie As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "http://reportserver.comp.local/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOperations%2fAR%2fCash+Receipts&StartDate=2017-01-07&EndDate=2017-01-13"
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_ButtonImgDown").Click
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu").Click
    ie.document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Button").Value = "Excel"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go through the Dropdown options and change the `selectedIndex` of that particular **Select** you are after. Try below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Report()
    Dim ie As Object, oSelection As Object, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    If ie Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://reportserver.comp.local/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOperations%2fAR%2fCash+Receipts&StartDate=2017-01-07&EndDate=2017-01-13"

        ' I am guessing this is the right id check page source code "<select id='...'"
        Set oSelection = .document.getelementbyid("ReportViewerControl_ctl05_ctl04_ctl00_Menu")

        If Not oSelection Is Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To oSelection.all.Length - 1
                If InStr(1, oSelection.all(i), "Excel", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    oSelection.selectedIndex = i
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            Set oSelection = Nothing
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
    Set ie = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The Excel option is the first option. I am a little confused on whether or not I am using the correct ID because there is one for the table, one for the button, one appears to be for the button image, one for the drop down menu...I have tried all of them and nothing is working. I was trying to see if I could write in something like:    Format=EXCELOPENXML but I guess its not that easy.

Comment: If you have FireFox, select the area or the selection drop down box, view the source code and you should be able to locate it. If you use IE, put a BreakPoint at `.Quit`, run the code and if not changing to your desired option, move yellow arrow to `If Not oSelection ...` then change the ID to one of the found ones in Immediate window `Set oSelection = .document.getelementbyid("next test id")`, then if your desired one changed, thats the one you need.